# Which machine learning method can take a matrix as input?

Tags: machine-learning, ai-design, reference-request

I am pretty new to the machine learning field. I want to use an $n \times m$ matrix as the input of a model, in order to predict a vector $1 \times m$, both of real numbers. Input data are quite clean, with statistics of about 10000 items.

Do you know a method that can handle that?

Comment: *Hint*: Start by flattening the $n\times m$ matrix to a $nm\times 1$ vector.

Answer (score 1):

ANNs can do the trick. Check out [sklearn's ANN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neural_networks/plot_mnist_filters.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-neural-networks-plot-mnist-filters-py) example with the Digits dataset, which consists of 28x28 pixel input data.